# How do I use AE2 to keep exactly 1 stack of an item in a chest?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods, minecraft-direwolf20, minecraft-applied-energistics

I've just started playing the direwolf20 1.7.10 pack, and have a basic AE system set up, with an ender chest and pouch to keep me supplied with food etc. However, it becomes full of bread (my food of choice) and nothing else. Is there a way for me to keep only 1 stack of bread in the chest and have it automatically replaced when I take it out?

Comment: I remember seeing direwolf doing this in his last series, but i dont remember the name of the device he used for this. I'll try and find out.

Answer (score 1):

by using both [item translocators](http://ftbwiki.org/Item_Translocator) and a [ME Interface](http://ae-mod.info/ME-Interface/) you can get what you want.

By placing one tranlocator on the chest and one on the interface then configuring(which is explained mostly on the item translocator wiki page) it how you want it. It should then keep a stack of the preferred item in the chest. For your case, put a stack of bread in any slot in the translocator. Note: you need the diamond nugget upgrade